# Instead of Disk, may just BURN my computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive, 64-bit, dvd

I have an old HP Compaq 6710B laptop which ran XP-PRO-SP3 32bit (x86) as sole OS. It has an un-bootable 160gb HDD and a HP (2008) Model No.UJ-861 HHC-A DVD=RW Drive.
I also have a Dell Latitude E6430 laptop running Windows 7 SP1 64bit, version 6.1.7601.17514 with a 119gb Samsung 2013 SSD SM841 2.5" 7 with a H+L Super Multi DVD Rewriter Model: GU7ON ROM ver A103 that works just fine.
Now the problem i'm having is using the Dell to download ISO files and burn them to disk but the HP's (with XP os) dvd drive isn't reading the files correctly, that is to say it doesn't seem to get up to speed as would normally and the HP just won't recognize the disk while it does others. (none of which are bootable)
Iv'e used Roxio, ImgBurn, Win7's burn system, Rufus and the only one that let me control the download bit process was ImgBurn but still the same results.
Now is this even a possible task, to use a 64bit formatted disk for a 32bit OS? And yes I am downloading 32bit or (x86) style ISO (.img) files. Any insight into this would be a great help and go a long way towards getting my sanity back and or emailing the laptop across the room lol.

The Beave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried burning the ISO in a pendrive, instead of a disk?

You can easily do it using [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](http://wudt.codeplex.com/), by choosing "USB device". You'll just need an empty pendrive and your ISO file.

*P.S.: Don't worry about the program being called "Windows **7** Download Tool", it works perfectly for other Windows versions ;)*